# Добавление данных в форму без перезагрузки

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица с данными. К ней добавляю ячейку, содержащую поле для ввода, после ее заполнения (нажав на ENTER) новые данные должны добавиться в таблицу.
Хочу добавлять введенные в ячейку данные прямо в верстку, без отправления их на сервер.
//При перезагрузке страницы они должны исчезать.
Как можно реализовать такое?

```js
$('.butForAdd').click(function() {
  var newLine = $('tr:last', tbl).clone();
  newLine.find('td').addClass('ClassOne').html('&nbsp;');

  tbl.append(newLine);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="butForAdd">Добавить</button>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Николай</td>
    <td>Владислав</td>
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: @Air , не знаю, в принципе, как такое реализовать без отправления данных на сервер.

Comment: Html сам напиши, а с js я тебе помогу...  Прикажешь за тебя все решать, что куда да как...  Поучаствуй в процессе...

Comment: @Air, написала (правила вопрос). Мне хоть намек на метод, или подсказка в какую сторону думать, не обязательно код за меня писать.

Comment: Юля, не могу понять из примера, что именно ты хочешь клонировать и куда вставить?  В `tr` еще одну ячейку `td` или хочешь клонировать целиком весь `td` и вставить в `table`

Comment: Странно, в Вашем коде уже есть практически все необходимое, копать не нужно уже особо, если это Ваш код...  нужно взять данные из input `.val()`, подставить их, выполнить `append`...

Comment: @Air ,Это просто пример,в проекте кода больше,суть в следующем: У меня есть таблица,в ней уже есть какие-то данные,по нажатию на кнопку ДОБАВИТЬ появляется новая строка(tr с ячейками td) с полем для ввода (input) пользователь вводит новые данные в ячейку. Хочу (по нажатию на ENTER) сделать добавление  данных(введенных пользователем)в таблицу. Если говорить о состояниях,то есть первое состояние:начальная страница с таблицей, второе состояние: добавление строки с полем для ввода и третье состояние, которое отличается от первого только тем,что таблица имеет новую строку с данными от пользователя.

Comment: @Air , клонируют строку (tr) с ячейками, добавляю в конец существующей таблицы

Comment: @Максим , данные в таблицу подгружаются с сервера. Введенные пользователем данные не нужно загружать на сервер, нужно их добавить на страницу (при этом никуда не отправляя) к уже существующей таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии я и не имел в виду, что нужно что-то с сервера отправлять. Как пример, можно добавлять элементы, используя `createElement` и `appendChild`

```js
function addNewTr(){
  var newTr, td1, td2;
  newTr = document.createElement('tr');
  td1 = document.createElement('td');
  td2 = document.createElement('td');
  $(td1).html($('#firstTdVal').val());
  $(td2).html($('#secondTdVal').val());
  newTr.appendChild(td1);
  newTr.appendChild(td2);
  $('#table').append(newTr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstTdVal" type="text" />
<input id="secondTdVal" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="добавить строку" onclick="addNewTr()" />

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Саша</td>
    <td>инженер</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Марина</td>
    <td>бухгалтер</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```